# Alternative of DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc-checkdb

I am running DBCC CHECKDB on one of my database but its taking very very long time. I have some questions please help me.

Is there any alternative of it that can check my database integrity?

Should I wait to finish it?

Comment: How Big DB are we talking here?

Comment: Also, what command have you run when you say DBCC CHECKDB

Answer (score 9):

The only alternative to performing consistency checking (`DBCC CHECKDB`) is to leave your data open to the possibility of corruption and data loss.

There are some ways to reduce the impact that `CHECKDB` has on your system. The best way to do this by far is to run your checks offline on a copy of your live systems. This should be done by restoring a full backup of your database onto another system and then running `DBCC CHECKDB` there. 
This is good for two reasons:

1. It off loads the IO and perfomance issues your are experiencing onto another machine
2. It tests your backups restore successfully.

If you can't afford to have a secondary server for testing backups and running `DBCC CHECKDB` then you may have to break the check down and run it against a few individual tables each night to spread the load out accross the week. You can do this with the `CHECKTABLE` statement. Another way to break the job into smaller parts would be to use `CHECKFILEGROUP` to check each file group, only makes sense if you have multiple file groups.

You can also try `trace flags 2549, 2562, and 2566`. For more information on the trace flags, the methods mentioned above and more read Aaron Bertrand's post on the subject [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/io-subsystem/minimize-impact-of-checkdb)